# Enrich table with data from other table

Tags: sql, join, teradata

Currently I have 2 tables: one with client data (CLIENT_TABLE) and one with gift card information (GIFTCARD_TABLE).

The GIFTCARD_TABLE consists of 100 rows and it has 2 columns: Card_Number and Pin_Code.

Now I need to enrich the CLIENT_TABLE (35 rows) with the 2 columns from the GIFTCARD_TABLE, so every client needs one card_number with its corresponding pin_code and it doesn't matter which one (just don't use the same card number & pin_code twice).

Since these tables don't have any keys which I can use, I don't know how I can do this.

Any suggestions how I can tackle this?

Kind regards

Comment: *Since these tables don't have any keys which I can use, I don't know how I can do this.* Does this means that these data are not related now, that none card belongs any definite client yet? And you need to assign 35 cards (from 100) to 35 clients randomly?

Comment: Teradata or MySQL?

Comment: Select one DBMS, either MySQL or Teradata, and remove unrelated tag. And specify precise DB server version.

Comment: @Akina Yes, they are unrelated and need to be assigned to 35 clients randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign the cards *truly random* you need:

```
select *
from
 (  -- random row_numbers
    select dt.*, 
       row_number() over (order by rnd) as rn
    from
     ( -- 35 random clients
       select t.*, random(1,1000000000) as rnd
       from CLIENT_TABLE as t
       sample randomized allocation 35
     ) as dt
 ) as client
join
 (  -- random row_numbers
    select dt.*, 
       row_number() over (order by rnd) as rn
    from
     ( 
       select t.*, random(1,1000000000) as rnd
       from GIFTCARD_TABLE as t
     ) as dt
 ) as card
on client.rn = card.rn
```

RANDOM can't be used directly in ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

Schematically (I may be incorrect in Teradata syntax):

```sql
UPDATE 
-- this table copy will be updated
     CLIENT_TABLE c1  
-- this CTE enumerates clients, join enumerates rows in 1st copy
JOIN ( SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
       FROM CLIENT_TABLE ) c2 ON c1.id = c2.id
-- this CTE enumerates cards, join assigns card to client one-to-one by the `rn` number
JOIN ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Card_Number) rn
       FROM GIFTCARD_TABLE ) g ON c2.rn = g.rn
SET c1.Card_Number = g.Card_Number,
    c1.Pin_Code = g.Pin_Code;
```